# Replacing similar strings with single unified string in python

Tags: python, data-science

Currently working on a data science project and I'm having trouble with data preparation.

Specifically this one: [What's Cooking?](https://www.kaggle.com/c/whats-cooking/)

The dataset has strings like *'medium eggs'*, *'large free range egg'*, *'eggplants'*, *'large egg whites'*, *'chinese egg noodles'* and *'eggs'*

So in this case, I would like to find and replace all the *'medium eggs'* and *'large free range egg'* as just *'eggs'* while strings like *'eggplants'* and *'chinese egg noodles'* are supposed to be left alone. I would also need to replace *'large egg whites'* as *'egg whites'*

Another case would be *'garbanzo beans'* and *'chick peas'* since they refer to the same ingredient.

The initial attempt was just to find any string with 'egg' in its string and replace it, but because there are so many conditions, I'm not sure what kind of approach to take now.

Since this is a classification project, the code needs to be able to take potential ingredients like 'small egg' and still understand it as *'eggs'*

Comment: May be create a dictionary like `{word_you_want_to_replace:replacement,...}` now you can make changes in the original dataset while iterating

Comment: As far as I understand, there is just 3 cases hence, you can write them manually to replace, without any trick.
Ex. your_str.replace("medium eggs", "eggs")

Comment: Oh that is just 1 case, there are plenty of ingredients in that data set that need to be editted in a similar manner up to hunderds

Comment: Honestly might have to go with whatever Ch3steR suggested due to how many complications there are with the actual ingredients

Answer (score 0):

This can be done most cleanly with regex, checking for spaces on either side of the query string:

```py
import re

def replace_eggs(string_to_replace, replacement_text, *query_strings):
  for query_string in query_strings:
    return re.sub(f"\s?{query_string}([\.,]?)\s?",replacement_text, string_to_replace)
```

WARNING: This code is *very* bad. It doesn't work very well, and I don't have enough time to fix it. I am sorry. I would suggest learning about regex and catch groups to do this a bit better. Just to re-iterate (ba-dum ching!), I'm sorry but I have many things to do.

Comment: This looks interestly, but it would still require me to look through every string I need to replace right?

Comment: Any code will eventually have to do that in the background

Answer (score 0):

As a partial solution, you could write a simple function using this:

```
import spacy

items = ['medium eggs', 'large free range egg', 'eggplants', 'large egg whites', 'chinese egg noodles', 'eggs']
clean = []
for i in items:
    doc = nlp(i)
    temp = ''
    for token in doc:
        #print(token.text , token.pos_)
        if token.pos_=='NOUN' or  token.pos_=='PROPN':
            temp += ' ' + token.text
    clean.append(temp)
print(clean)
```

Output: `[' eggs', ' range egg', ' eggplants', ' egg whites', ' egg noodles', ' eggs']`

NOTE: You might need to take care of a few cases like 'garbanzo beans' and 'chick peas' manually